# sudo rsync locally lack of permission

Tags: macos, localhost, rsync, sudo, permission-denied

What is the command to LOCALLY Rsync a bunch of folders that by default rsync doesnt have the necessary rights for. (in the terminal i have to sudo rsync for that matter). But in a shell script it works a little different.

I have been reading about

```
rsync --rsh-path="sudo rsync" -aq...
```

and another said:

```
rsync --rsh="ssh me@Mac sudo" -aq...
```

And all the others are talking about remote rsyncing.
but none of local ones seem to work.

Someone can shine a light on this?
cheerz!

Answer (score 0):

if you work locally just run rsync with escalated rights and leave out all the other options like so:

```
sudo rsync -avP source target
```

you can replace `-avP` of course to fit your needs about what information gets transferred and what output is generated.

Comment: this doesn't do anything for rsyncing locally with different rights. Rights, which are set to: _mysql:wheel by-the-way. The tcsh file i am using to initiate the rsync holds the rights joland:staff. I am taking mac here.